# Connect to WPS WiFi

Tags: android, wps

I want to make an app where the user activate the WPS clicking in the button of the internet box and after press to a button in the app and the app search automatically the WPS network.

But first I try to connect the user to a specific WPS Wifi.
How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the oslution using the WifiManager's `startWps()` method:

```
mWifiManager.startWps(wpsConfig, mWpsCallback);
```

Comment: Hi. I'm looking for an app (already made, or not), that allow me to connect a `Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (model GT-P5200)` (Android 4.2.2) to any WPS Wi-Fi AP. I found this solution some days ago, but it is suposed to work on Android 5.0+. Did you tryed to use this on Jelly Bean? Thanks in advance.